# Composition of rules: a->b + b->c = a->c

Tags: replacement, rule

I am trying to compose two rules to form a new one:

`{a -> b, b -> d}` and `{b -> c}` should become `{a -> c, b -> d}`.

This was my attempt:

```
{a -> b, b -> d} /. ((lhs_ -> rhs_) ->  (lhs -> (rhs /. {b -> c)))
```

However, this just yields `{a -> b, b -> d}`. Somehow the second rule does not apply. If I hardcode `rhs` to `b` the substitution does work.

What am I missing?

Comment: try `:>` (`RuleDelayed`).

Comment: or using the `MapAt` way : `MapAt[f, {a -> b, b -> d}, {All, 2}]`, in your case `MapAt[# /. b -> c &, {a -> b, b -> d}, {All, 2}]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
{a -> b, b -> d, c -> b} /. Rule[x_, b] :> Rule[x, c]
```

> {a -> c, b -> d, c -> c}

This `ReplaceAll` (`/.`) replaced all right hand side b's with c's. The `MapAt` solution proposed by @SquareOne would give the same result. If you want to apply the replacement to specific rules you could use

```
ReplacePart[{a -> b, b -> d, c -> b}, 1 :> a -> c]
```

{a -> c, b -> d, c -> b}

Answer (score 0):

You can observe both sublists simultaneously using patterns,

```
{{a -> b, 
   b -> d}, {b -> c}} //. {{s___, Rule[a_, b_], c___}, {q___, 
    Rule[b_, w_], d___}} :> {s, Rule[a, w], c}

=> {a -> c, b -> d}
```